# Football during the COVID-19 lockdown

Tags: football

During the next few months, we will have football behind closed doors. Teams like Liverpool and Dortmund always have a great impact from their fans, whereas some teams play better in away environments without home fan pressure.

Wouldn't this new system give an advantage to these teams?

Also, to compensate the lost months, rumors say that we may have more than 2 games every week, which will be a big disadvantage to teams which have fewer options for their starting 11.

Did FIFA consider these factors while making decisions?

Answer (score 1):

> some teams play better in away environments without home fan pressure.
>
> Wouldn't this new system give an advantage to these teams?

Not necessarily. I don't believe football has ever been played behind closed doors on such a massive scale before. Whether the empty stadiums will help teams who play better away from home, or hurt teams who play better at home, remains to be seen. (My naive understanding, though, is that teams who play better away from home are *very* rare.)

> rumors say that we may have more than 2 games every week, which will be a big disadvantage to teams which have fewer options for their starting 11.

If that *is* just a rumour, then it might not actually happen, in which case it's a moot point. However, FIFA *have* accounted for potential fixture congestion: [teams will be able to make five substitutions](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/52592431) instead of the usual three.